# VHDL error in compilation

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl, alu

I'm new in VHDL and I'm trying to create an ALU but it has some errors in compilations.Here is the code :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.basic_func.all;

entity askhsh1 is
  port
(   a : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    b : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    coin : in std_logic;
    coout : out std_logic;
    s : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    d : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    result : out std_logic);


end askhsh1;

architecture structure of askhsh1 is 
  signal c : std_logic_vector(1 to 15);
  signal resultAND : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal resultOR : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal operator : std_logic_vector(0 to 2);
  signal resultXOR : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal binvert : std_logic;
  signal ainvert : std_logic;
  component myAND
    port (in1, in2: in std_logic; out1: out std_logic);
  end component;
  component myOR
    port (in1, in2: in std_logic; out1: out std_logic);
  end component;
  component myXOR
    port (in1, in2: in std_logic; out1: out std_logic);
  end component;
  component fullader
    port (cin, x, y : in std_logic; 
            s, cout : out std_logic);
  end component;
begin 
U1 : myAND port map (a, b, resultAND);

T1 : myOR port map (a, b, resultOR);

 stage0 : fulladder port map (cin => coin, x => a(0),  y => b(0), s => s(0), cout => c(1));
 stage1 : fulladder port map (cin => c(1), x => a(1),  y => b(1), s => s(1), cout => c(2));
 stage2 : fulladder port map (cin => c(2), x => a(2),  y => b(2), s => s(2), cout => c(3));
 stage3 : fulladder port map (cin => c(3), x => a(3),  y => b(3), s => s(3), cout => c(4));
 stage4 : fulladder port map (cin => c(4), x => a(4),  y => b(4), s => s(4), cout => c(5));
 stage5 : fulladder port map (cin => c(5), x => a(5),  y => b(5), s => s(5), cout => c(6));
 stage6 : fulladder port map (cin => c(6), x => a(6),  y => b(6), s => s(6), cout => c(7));
 stage7 : fulladder port map (cin => c(7), x => a(7),  y => b(7), s => s(7), cout => c(8));
 stage8 : fulladder port map (cin => c(8), x => a(8),  y => b(8), s => s(8), cout => c(9));
 stage9 : fulladder port map (cin => c(9), x => a(9),  y => b(9), s => s(9), cout => c(10));
 stage10 : fulladder port map (cin => c(10), x => a(10),  y => b(10), s => s(10), cout => c(11));
 stage11 : fulladder port map (cin => c(11), x => a(11),  y => b(11), s => s(11), cout => c(12));
 stage12 : fulladder port map (cin => c(12), x => a(12),  y => b(12), s => s(12), cout => c(13));
 stage13 : fulladder port map (cin => c(13), x => a(13),  y => b(13), s => s(13), cout => c(14));
 stage14 : fulladder port map (cin => c(14), x => a(14),  y => b(14), s => s(14), cout => c(15));
 stage15 : fulladder port map (cin => c(15), x => a(15),  y => b(15), s => s(15), cout => coout);

 stage0 : fulladder port map (cin => '1', x => a(0), y => (not b(0)), s => s(0), cout => c(1));
 stage1 : fulladder port map (cin => c(1), x => a(1), y => (not b(1)), s => s(1), cout => c(2));
 stage2 : fulladder port map (cin => c(2), x => a(2), y => (not b(2)), s => s(2), cout => c(3));
 stage3 : fulladder port map (cin => c(3), x => a(3), y => (not b(3)), s => s(3), cout => c(4));
 stage4 : fulladder port map (cin => c(4), x => a(4), y => (not b(4)), s => s(4), cout => c(5));
 stage5 : fulladder port map (cin => c(5), x => a(5), y => (not b(5)), s => s(5), cout => c(6));
 stage6 : fulladder port map (cin => c(6), x => a(6), y => (not b(6)), s => s(6), cout => c(7));
 stage7 : fulladder port map (cin => c(7), x => a(7), y => (not b(7)), s => s(7), cout => c(8));
 stage8 : fulladder port map (cin => c(8), x => a(8), y => (not b(8)), s => s(8), cout => c(9));
 stage9 : fulladder port map (cin => c(9), x => a(9), y => (not b(9)), s => s(9), cout => c(10));
 stage10 : fulladder port map (cin => c(10), x => a(10), y => (not b(10)), s => s(10), cout => c(11));
 stage11 : fulladder port map (cin => c(11), x => a(11), y => (not b(11)), s => s(11), cout => c(12));
 stage12 : fulladder port map (cin => c(12), x => a(12), y => (not b(12)), s => s(12), cout => c(13));
 stage13 : fulladder port map (cin => c(13), x => a(13), y => (not b(13)), s => s(13), cout => c(14));
 stage14 : fulladder port map (cin => c(14), x => a(14), y => (not b(14)), s => s(14), cout => c(15));
 stage15 : fulladder port map (cin => c(15), x => a(15), y => (not b(15)), s => s(15), cout =>coout);

 stage0 : fulladder port map (cin => '1', x => (not a(0)), y => b(0), s => s(0), cout => c(1));
 stage1 : fulladder port map (cin => c(1), x =>(not a(1)), y => b(1), s => s(1), cout => c(2));
 stage2 : fulladder port map (cin => c(2), x =>(not a(2)), y => b(2), s => s(2), cout => c(3));
 stage3 : fulladder port map (cin => c(3), x =>(not a(3)), y => b(3), s => s(3), cout => c(4));
 stage4 : fulladder port map (cin => c(4), x =>(not a(4)), y => b(4), s => s(4), cout => c(5));
 stage5 : fulladder port map (cin => c(5), x =>(not a(5)), y => b(5), s => s(5), cout => c(6));
 stage6 : fulladder port map (cin => c(6), x =>(not a(6)), y => b(6), s => s(6), cout => c(7));
 stage7 : fulladder port map (cin => c(7), x =>(not a(7)), y => b(7), s => s(7), cout => c(8));
 stage8 : fulladder port map (cin => c(8), x =>(not a(8)), y => b(8), s => s(8), cout => c(9));
 stage9 : fulladder port map (cin => c(9), x =>(not a(9)), y => b(9), s => s(9), cout => c(10));
 stage10 : fulladder port map (cin => c(10), x =>(not a(10)), y => b(10), s => s(10), cout => c(11));
 stage11 : fulladder port map (cin => c(11), x =>(not a(11)), y => b(11), s => s(11), cout => c(12));
 stage12 : fulladder port map (cin => c(12), x =>(not a(12)), y => b(12), s => s(12), cout => c(13));
 stage13 : fulladder port map (cin => c(13), x =>(not a(13)), y => b(13), s => s(13), cout => c(14));
 stage14 : fulladder port map (cin => c(14), x =>(not a(14)), y => b(14), s => s(14), cout => c(15));
 stage15 : fulladder port map (cin => c(15), x =>(not a(15)), y => b(15), s => s(15), cout => coout);

 P1 : myXOR port map (a, b, resultXOR);

 case (operator) is
    when 0 => output <= resultAND;
    when 1 => output <= resultOR;
    when 2 => 
        if binvert = '0' and ainvert = '0' then
            output <= s;
        elsif binvert = '1' and ainvert = '0' then
            output <= s;
        elsif ainvert = '1' and binvert = '0' then
            output <= s;
        end if;
 end case;



end structure;
```

The errors are the following :

- Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at askhsh1.vhd(97) near text "case";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("case" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement.
- Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at askhsh1.vhd(97) near text "is";  expecting "<="
- Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at askhsh1.vhd(99) near text "when";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("when" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement
- Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at askhsh1.vhd(100) near text "when";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("when" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement
- Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at askhsh1.vhd(103) near text "elsif";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("elsif" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement
- Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at askhsh1.vhd(105) near text "elsif";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("elsif" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement
- Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at askhsh1.vhd(107) near text "if";  expecting ";", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or "architecture"
- Info (12021): Found 0 design units, including 0 entities, in source file askhsh1.vhd
- Info (12021): Found 9 design units, including 4 entities, in source file basic_func.vhd
  Info (12022): Found design unit 1: basic_func
  Info (12022): Found design unit 2: myAND-modeland
  Info (12022): Found design unit 3: myOR-modelor
  Info (12022): Found design unit 4: myXOR-modelxor
  Info (12022): Found design unit 5: fulladder-modelfulla
  Info (12023): Found entity 1: myAND
  Info (12023): Found entity 2: myOR
  Info (12023): Found entity 3: myXOR
  Info (12023): Found entity 4: fulladder
- Error (293001): Quartus II Full Compilation was unsuccessful. 9 errors, 1 warning

Comment: The first error tells you : you can't use sequential statements where concurrent statements are expected. At least, unlike michie_dc who's posted a substantial chunk of this code, you reported what the error is.

Comment: So how can I resolve it ?

Comment: Either use an equivalent concurrent statement, or put the sequential statement where sequential statements are allowed. Your choice.

Comment: Can you please give me an example ?

Comment: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/concurrent.html the top hit in google for "VHDL concurrent statements"

Comment: So I have to remove the if-else statement ?

Comment: Also see [VHDL program doesn' t compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073331/vhdl-program-doesn-t-compile) by D. Noze.  In your specific case there is no driver for operator, ainvert or binvert. Place scary_jeff's case statement inside a process statement. (It's also worth following the link in Brian's concurrent.html to Sequential Statements).

Comment: Ok i put the case inside a process statement but how can i use the ainvert and the binvert?

Comment: From a HW perspective you have three adders where you only need one. ainvert and binvert should be used to [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) either the a or b operand to a single adder. These three questions collectively aren't showing research effort. (3rd question [VHDL code compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093084/vhdl-code-compilation-error) by michie dc).

Comment: So if i create a component for ainvert and a component for binvert that two's complement the a and b then how can I use them in a single adder?